# SQLSERVER / Foxpro Linked server issue

Tags: sql-server, oledb, linked-server, foxpro

I am currently performing a migration of data from an old legacy system.  This system runs on FoxPro tables which I have had no personal exposure to until now. I have installed a fresh copy of SQL2014 32 bit (no 64 bit driver for Visual FoxPro) and installed the VFPOLEDB.dll provider which shows in management studio fine.

I have set up my linked server through the GUI and tested the connection and all appears fine.

[image: Linked Server Setup]

I have also set the "Allow inprocess" option on the provider. When I expand the linked server I see no tables or views.

[image: Missing Tables]

So I have got to the point where SSMS recognises that there is a linked server in place, but I still can't see any data on here.

I can pull the data table by table into excel, and then re-insert every table into sql manually, but that is going to be an exceptionally long task.

Any help gratefully received! Many thanks.

Comment: As an aside, if you have an MSDN subscription you could grab Visual FoxPro 9 and use the SQL Server Upsizing Wizard in that.

Comment: Hi Alan. Thanks for that, was one of my options. At the moment I'm only preparing scripts and performing test migrations, the actual migration isn't going to happen just yet so data isn't finalised. That may end up being the way that we go though if we can't get the linked server approach up and running.

Comment: There are examples here of accessing DBF files from T-SQL: http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki~VisualFoxProDataFromSQLServer~VFP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Alan B for the link posted above, while it wasn't the answer it sent me in the right direction.

Issue seems to be two fold. First that the linked server doesn't like UNC addresses. So linking to \Servername\data was not going to work. At all. That's first issue.

Second issue came down to a lack of knowledge around FoxPro on my part. My documentation stated that the package I'm migrating from stored data in filename.dbc which I copied locally to my machine for testing, along with filename.DCT & filename.DCX.

This was only enough for me to access the top level of the database, i.e. make a connection to it, but not to see the sub tables which are stored in individual files.

My assumption was that all the tables were held in one file (similar to access) however this was incorrect. I had to copy entire directory contents to my local machine and this gave me access to all the sub tables.

So in short UNC path is a non starter, so copy files locally. Ensure you copy all files not just the top level that you access.

Many thanks for your help and support on this.

Comment: The DBC/DCT/DCX files are the 'database container', which themselves are just DBF files containing metadata about the 'database'. The database is the collection of DBF files that the DBC has an internal list of which belong to it. In addition, the DBF files have a a 'backlink' saying which DBC they belong to.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. This basically shows my lack of understanding of fox pro. Fortunately we're moving away from our old system into a SQL server based solution. At least there I feel more at home. Thanks again.